# The layout gets messed up on adding citation to markdown in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter, bibliography

I am trying to add citations in a markdown document using

````
\```
{bibliography}
:filter: docname in docnames
:style: unsrt
\```
````

However the the width of the column gets reduced and messed up the layout.
Similar to the one they have in the documentation as well: https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/content/citations.html

As you can clearly see the layout is messed up in the above link (from the previous and next buttons at the bottom)

However with same config, it works fine here: https://thomasfermi.github.io/Algorithms-for-Automated-Driving/CameraCalibration/Discussion.html

What do I need to do to fix this ?